# State getting reinitialized to its original value - useState or useReduce

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I created a custom hook (`useAuth`) to extend the third-party Authentication service Auth0's useAuth0 hook and set some local variables that holds basic user information, such as userId.

I have a master account that can impersonate other accounts. This means that it overrides the userId from my custom hook and it gets propagated throughout the system.

The problem that I'm facing is that whenever I call the `impersonate` function that changes this hook's inner state, it changes it, but then reinitializes itself. I don't know what is causing this reinitialization. The code is down below.

```
import { useAuth0 } from '@auth0/auth0-react';
import produce from 'immer';
import { useState, useEffect, useCallback, useReducer, Reducer } from 'react';
import { AccountType, Auth0HookUser, TenantInfo, TenantType } from '../@dts';

type AuthVariants =
  | 'INDIVIDUAL_TEACHER'
  | 'INSTITUTION_TEACHER'
  | 'STUDENT'
  | 'SECRETARY'
  | 'COORDINATOR'
  | 'ADMINISTRATOR';

type AuthTenant = {
  accountType: AccountType;
  tenantType: TenantType;
  employeeId: string;
  tenantId: string;
  selectedTenant: TenantInfo;
  variant: AuthVariants;
  mode: 'IMPERSONATION' | 'NORMAL';
  user: Auth0HookUser;
};

const defaultAuthTenant: () => AuthTenant = () => ({
  accountType: 'teacher',
  employeeId: '',
  mode: 'NORMAL',
  selectedTenant: {
    accountType: 'teacher',
    tenantType: 'INSTITUTION',
    tenantId: '',
  },
  tenantId: '',
  tenantType: 'INSTITUTION',
  variant: 'INDIVIDUAL_TEACHER',
  user: {
    name: '',
    nickname: '',
  } as any,
});

type Action =
  | {
      type: 'UPDATE_AUTH';
      auth: AuthTenant;
    }
  | {
      type: 'IMPERSONATE';
      impersonatedEmployeeId: string;
      impersonatedName: string;
      accountType: AccountType;
    }
  | {
      type: 'EXIT_IMPERSONATION';
    };

type State = {
  current: AuthTenant;
  original: AuthTenant;
};

const reducer = produce((state: State, action: Action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'IMPERSONATE':
      console.log('Impersonating');
      const selectedTenant =
        state.current.user['https://app.schon.io/user_data'].tenants[0];
      state.current = {
        ...state.current,
        user: {
          ...state.current.user,
          name: action.impersonatedName,
          nickname: action.impersonatedName,
          'https://app.schon.io/user_data': {
            ...state.current.user['https://app.schon.io/user_data'],
            userId: action.impersonatedEmployeeId,
          },
        },
        mode: 'IMPERSONATION',
        accountType: action.accountType,
        employeeId: action.impersonatedEmployeeId,
        variant: getVariant(action.accountType, selectedTenant.tenantType),
        selectedTenant: {
          ...state.current.selectedTenant,
          accountType: action.accountType,
        },
      };
      return state;
    case 'UPDATE_AUTH':
      state.current = action.auth;
      state.original = action.auth;
      return state;
    default:
      return state;
  }
});

export function useAuth() {
  const { user: _user, isAuthenticated, isLoading, ...auth } = useAuth0();
  const user = _user as Auth0HookUser;

  const [selectedTenantIndex, setSelectedTenantIndex] = useState(0);
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer<Reducer<State, Action>>(reducer, {
    current: defaultAuthTenant(),
    original: defaultAuthTenant(),
  });

  const impersonate = (
    impersonatedEmployeeId: string,
    accountType: AccountType,
    impersonatedName: string,
  ) => {
    if (!user) {
      return;
    }

    dispatch({
      type: 'IMPERSONATE',
      accountType,
      impersonatedEmployeeId,
      impersonatedName,
    });
  };

  const exitImpersonation = useCallback(() => {
    dispatch({ type: 'EXIT_IMPERSONATION' });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isLoading || (!isLoading && !isAuthenticated)) {
      return;
    }
    if (!user || state.current.mode === 'IMPERSONATION') {
      return;
    }
    console.log('Use Effect Running');
    const { tenants, userId } = user['https://app.schon.io/user_data'];
    const selectedTenant = tenants[selectedTenantIndex];
    const { accountType, tenantType } = selectedTenant;

    dispatch({
      type: 'UPDATE_AUTH',
      auth: {
        tenantId: selectedTenant.tenantId,
        employeeId: userId,
        mode: 'NORMAL',
        variant: getVariant(accountType, tenantType),
        user,
        selectedTenant,
        accountType,
        tenantType,
      },
    });
  }, [
    user,
    isAuthenticated,
    isLoading,
    selectedTenantIndex,
    state.current.mode,
  ]);

  console.log('State Current', state.current);
  return {
    isAuthenticated,
    isLoading,
    impersonate,
    exitImpersonation,
    setSelectedTenantIndex,
    ...auth,
    ...state.current,
  };
}

function getVariant(
  accountType: AccountType,
  tenantType: TenantType,
): AuthVariants {
  if (accountType === 'teacher') {
    return tenantType === 'INSTITUTION'
      ? 'INSTITUTION_TEACHER'
      : 'INDIVIDUAL_TEACHER';
  }
  return accountType.toUpperCase() as AuthVariants;
}
```

See the picture. After I call the impersonate function it sets it to the impersonated mode but re-initializes itself and sets it to the default.

[image]

This is what I've tried:

- Double Checked that proper dependencies were passed to the useEffect (it is not the one causing the re-initialize).
- I was using a useStae before the reducer, and I was calling it via its function vs setting the state directly.
- I tried stepping in (debugging) throughout the entire cycle, and didn't find anything.
- I went through several SO posts and React dosc to see if I could find any issues, but my blinded eye couldn't see it.

Here's a view where I'm calling it from (See the `const {impersonate} = useAuth()`) :

```
import React, { memo, useCallback, useMemo, useState } from 'react';
import { RouteComponentProps } from '@reach/router';
import { Button, Typography } from 'components';
import Skeleton from 'react-loading-skeleton';
import { useAuth } from '../../../../../auth';
import { Tabs, Dialog } from '../../../../../components/';
import { useAllClassesAndTeacherForInstitution } from '../../../../../graphql';
import { useThemeSpacing } from '../../../../../shared-styles/material-ui';
import { AddClassTeacher, ListClassTeacher } from './components';

type TeacherViewRouteProps = {
  teacherId: string;
};

export const TeacherView: React.FC<RouteComponentProps<
  TeacherViewRouteProps
>> = memo((props) => {
  const { impersonate } = useAuth();
  const { teacherId } = props;
  const { data, loading } = useAllClassesAndTeacherForInstitution(teacherId!);
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const openDialog = useCallback(() => setOpen(true), []);
  const closeDialog = useCallback(() => setOpen(false), []);

  const spacing = useThemeSpacing(4)();
  const teacherName = `${data?.teacher.name.fullName}`;
  const impersonateTeacher = useCallback(() => {
    if (!teacherName || !teacherId) {
      return;
    }
    impersonate(teacherId!, 'teacher', teacherName);
    closeDialog();
    // props?.navigate?.('/');
  }, [impersonate, closeDialog, teacherId, teacherName]);

  const tabOptions = useMemo(
    () => [
      {
        label: `Clases de ${teacherName}`,
      },
      {
        label: 'Agregar Clases',
      },
    ],
    [teacherName],
  );

  return (
    <>
      <Typography variant="h1" className={spacing.marginTopBottom}>
        {(loading && <Skeleton />) || teacherName}
      </Typography>
      <Dialog
        title={`Entrar en la cuenta de ${teacherName}`}
        open={open}
        onAgree={impersonateTeacher}
        onClose={closeDialog}
      >
        ¿Desea visualizar la cuenta de {teacherName}?
        <br />
        Si desea salir de la misma por favor refresque la página.
      </Dialog>
      <Button className={spacing.marginTopBottom} onClick={openDialog}>
        Entrar en cuenta de {teacherName || 'maestro'}
      </Button>

      {process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' && (
        <>
          <Tabs options={tabOptions}>
            <>
              {data?.teacher.klasses && (
                <ListClassTeacher
                  klasses={data.teacher.klasses}
                  teacherName={teacherName || 'maestro'}
                />
              )}
            </>
            <>
              {data?.grades && (
                <AddClassTeacher
                  existingClasses={data?.teacher.klasses || []}
                  grades={data.grades}
                  teacherId={teacherId!}
                />
              )}
            </>
          </Tabs>
        </>
      )}
    </>
  );
});

export default TeacherView;
```

Here's the initial Provider:

```
import React, { Suspense, memo } from 'react';
import { Location } from '@reach/router';
import { ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core';
import { ApolloProvider } from '@apollo/client';
import { theme } from 'components';

import { Auth0Provider } from '@auth0/auth0-react';
import CircularLoader from './components/CircularProgress';
import { useGlobalClient } from './utilities/client';
import { Layout } from './views/Layout';
import { Root } from './views/Root';
import { enableIfNotPreRendering } from './utilities/isPrerendering';
import { AUTH_CONFIG } from './auth/auth0.variables';
console.log('AUTH CONFIG', AUTH_CONFIG);
function App() {
  // This will be a method to enable faster loading times.
  /**\
   * Main AppMethod which hosts the site. To improve FCP it was split into
   * 2 files: The main file which will load the <Home component without any
   * dependencies (making it extremely fast to load at the beginning as it won't)
   * download all the code on its entirety.
   *
   * All consumers that are descendants of a Provider will re-render whenever the Provider’s value prop changes.
   * The propagation from Provider to its descendant consumers is not subject to the
   * shouldComponentUpdate method, so the consumer is updated even when an ancestor component
   * bails out of the update.
   *
   * Check this out whenever you're planning on implementing offline capabilities:
   * https://dev.to/willsamu/how-to-get-aws-appsync-running-with-offline-support-and-react-hooks-678
   */
  return (
    <Suspense fallback={<CircularLoader scrollsToTop={true} />}>
      <Location>
        {({ location }) => (
          <Auth0Provider
            {...AUTH_CONFIG}
            location={{ pathname: location.pathname, hash: location.hash }}
          >
            <ProviderForClient />
          </Auth0Provider>
        )}
      </Location>
    </Suspense>
  );
}

/**
 * This is done like this because we are using the useAuth0 Hook
 * and we need it to be after the Auth0Provider!!
 * @param props
 */
export const ProviderForClient: React.FC = (props) => {
  const globalClient = useGlobalClient();
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <ApolloProvider client={globalClient.current as any}>
        <Layout>
          <>{enableIfNotPreRendering() && <Root />}</>
        </Layout>
      </ApolloProvider>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
};

export default memo(App);
```

Comment: Just wondering, I believe it is dangerous to allow impersonation through client side since a potencial hacker could impersonate for very action

Comment: @Manjar: Thank you so much for the concern (Please see if I have a flaw in my logic). Only the administrator of the site is able to do so. Whenever a user sends a request, it sends a signed JWT with the original user's values (these are never modified). This is checked against the sent userId and a tenantId. If the tenantId matches, but the user doesn't, it checks for an accountType and role (which comes from the signed JWT), if they don't match the administrator, it rejects the request.

Answer (score 0):

I feel retarded. The hook was functioning normally. There's nothing wrong with the approach above (some other things can be debated). The problem was that I was not passing the hook via a context, but I was just calling the hook on each of the components. This meant that the hook was recreating the state (as it should be) per component, so whenever I updated the state, it would only be stated in one component.

That was it. I just had to rewrite the hook as a component and share it with a context.

Here's the final code (omitted some typings due to brevity)

```
const AuthContext = createContext<Context>({
  isAuthenticated: false,
  isLoading: false,
  getAccessTokenSilently() {
    return '' as any;
  },
  getAccessTokenWithPopup() {
    return '' as any;
  },
  getIdTokenClaims() {
    return '' as any;
  },
  loginWithPopup() {
    return '' as any;
  },
  loginWithRedirect() {
    return '' as any;
  },
  logout() {
    return '' as any;
  },
  impersonate(a: string, b: AccountType, c: string) {},
  exitImpersonation() {},
  setSelectedTenantIndex(i: number) {},
  accountType: 'teacher',
  employeeId: '',
  mode: 'NORMAL',
  selectedTenant: {
    accountType: 'teacher',
    tenantType: 'INSTITUTION',
    tenantId: '',
  },
  tenantId: '',
  tenantType: 'INSTITUTION',
  user: {
    name: '',
    nickname: '',
  } as any,
  variant: 'INSTITUTION_TEACHER',
});

/**
 * A custom wrapper for Auth. This allows us to set impersonation
 */
export const Auth: React.FC = memo((props) => {
  const { user: _user, isAuthenticated, isLoading, ...auth } = useAuth0();
  const user = _user as Auth0HookUser;

  const defaultUser = useCallback(
    (user?: Auth0HookUser) => getDefaultAuthTenant(user),
    [],
  );

  const [selectedTenantIndex, setSelectedTenantIndex] = useState(0);
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer<Reducer<State, Action>>(reducer, {
    current: defaultUser(_user),
    original: defaultUser(_user),
  });

  const calledDispatch = useCallback(dispatch, [dispatch]);

  const impersonate = useCallback(
    (
      impersonatedEmployeeId: string,
      accountType: AccountType,
      impersonatedName: string,
    ) => {
      if (!user) {
        return;
      }
      calledDispatch({
        type: 'IMPERSONATE',
        accountType,
        impersonatedEmployeeId,
        impersonatedName,
      });
    },
    [calledDispatch, user],
  );

  const exitImpersonation = useCallback(() => {
    dispatch({ type: 'EXIT_IMPERSONATION' });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isLoading || (!isLoading && !isAuthenticated)) {
      return;
    }
    if (!user || state.current.mode === 'IMPERSONATION') {
      return;
    }
    const { tenants, userId } = user['https://app.schon.io/user_data'];
    const selectedTenant = tenants[selectedTenantIndex];
    const { accountType, tenantType } = selectedTenant;

    dispatch({
      type: 'UPDATE_AUTH',
      auth: {
        tenantId: selectedTenant.tenantId,
        employeeId: userId,
        mode: 'NORMAL',
        variant: getVariant(accountType, tenantType),
        user,
        selectedTenant,
        accountType,
        tenantType,
      },
    });
    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, [
    user,
    isAuthenticated,
    isLoading,
    selectedTenantIndex,
    state.current.mode,
  ]);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={{
        isAuthenticated,
        isLoading,
        impersonate,
        exitImpersonation,
        setSelectedTenantIndex,
        ...auth,
        ...state.current,
      }}
    >
      {props.children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
});

export function useAuth() {
  const context = useContext(AuthContext);
  if (!context) {
    throw new Error(
      'You need to place the AuthContext below the Auth0Context and on top of the app',
    );
  }
  return context;
}
```

Now, I just placed the `<Auth/>` component on the top of my app.